# Enable and disable a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, uibarbuttonitem

I have a screen with 6 UITextFields and 1 UIBarButtonItem called "Done".  As soon as the user type anything on any of the 6 UITextFields I would like to enable my UIBarButtonItem called "Done", and also if the user delete the content I would like to return my UIBarByttonItem called "done" to disable mode. I would like to apply the same rule that Apple applied when you are adding a new contact in the iphone agenda. As soon as you type any information you are allowed to tap "done". Is there any smart way to that?

Many thanks,
Marcos.

Comment: Dude did any of the 4 answers help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to setup a method to be called whenever a text field is changed. Apply this same method to all of the text fields. In the method, you check if the text field has text or not. Based on that check, you enable or disable the button.

```
// Do this for each text field.
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldChangedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

- (void)textFieldChangedAction:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField.text.length) {
        // enable button
    } else {
        // In this method, check every text field for text. If any have text, enable button
        // If none have text, disable button.
    }
}
```

Edit:

You will need an instance variable for all of the text fields so you can access all of them to see if the button should be disabled or not.

Comment: @vilelam See the update I made regarding needing instance variables.

Comment: +1 for `if (textField.text.length) {
        // enable button
    } `. You dont have to compare all textfields for enabling the button. That was the point I was trying to say in my answer.

Comment: @R.A you cant't make such a claim with no explanation.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry.. Just check my answer.. Before downvoting tell me if there is any issue..

Comment: @R.A If the current text field has text then you can enable the button. Otherwise you need to check all of the others. There is no need to check every text field every time, only if the current is empty. The requirement is if at least one has text, not if all have text.

Comment: ya i have a code with '||' only. If any having text, then it enables the button.. If current didn't have text, then you will do as same as I did in my code??

Comment: I may didnt see the comment inside your else part well..Any way it will work. Sorry for my interrupt..

Comment: Thank you very much for all the effort you guys did.

Comment: @rmaddy Your approach was the one that I chose for my code. When the UIControlEventEditingChanged is launched all of my instances variables were already updated and it makes the code safer than using the delegate method ( textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)

Answer (score 1):

Implement the delegate method `– textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` and check if `[textfield.text length] > 0`. If yes, do `[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setEnabled:YES];` Do the same thing for disabling, but you need to check if for all the textfields in this case to make sure that none of them got any text.

```
- (BOOL) textField: (UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange)range replacementString: (NSString *)string { 

  NSString *text = [theTextField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];   
  if ([text length] > 0){    
     [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setEnabled:YES];    
  } else {
//check for all textfields and then set [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO]; In place of current textfield, you have to use `text`
  }
  return YES;
}
```

The advantage with this approach is that you dont have to add actions or notifications to all 6 textfields. Since the delegate is already setup, you dont have to worry about that.

Comment: Checking the text field's text length in this delegate may give the wrong answer (at least for the current text field).

Comment: This delegate is common for all textfields, so in case if any of the textfield changes its text this will be called. Hence it should work. Only problem is while disabling, he needs to check for all textfields using and condition. But that is needed in any case. As per his question if any of the textfield has text, it should be enabled and this if condition will be true if any of the textfield has text.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I'm already doing that but at the delegate method I have the ability to check only one of my six UITextField. I'll end up checking all of them all the time the above method is calling. I don't think this is going to be the best approach. but…

Comment: @ACB Assuming you were replying to me - your check will fail if the user is deleting all of the current text in the text field.

Comment: @rmaddy, Sorry, but I am still not getting your point. If the user deletes text from current textField, it will execute else part where he has to anyway compare all the textfield to decide whether to disable or not. And in case user is removing all text, barbutton would have already enabled before coming to this part(Since it would have called earlier to enable it). So how will this fail?

Comment: @ACB - no, when this delegate is called, the text field's text has not yet been updated. So the length will still reflect the current text, not the soon-to-be-new text. Remember, the point of this delegate is to specify whether the test should be changed or not.

Comment: @rmaddy, Okay got it. So your point is that I should be checking after that. Sorry, my bad. Corrected the answer.

Comment: @ACB Your updated code will work. Or just call the method I setup instead of this delegate method. :)

Comment: @rmaddy, yup, I got it now. I was thinking that the comment was about the `if condition` I had. I didnt think about the delegate method which I used. Upvoted yours.

Comment: Using this method keeps from having to add actions for all of the text fields...  +1

Comment: @lnafziger, Thanks. :) Yes, that is the advantage with using the delegate methods which are already available. We dont have to do that repeatedly for all textfields. All of them will ideally will call this since we would have already set `.delegate = self;`

Comment: Or, more likely, set the delegate in a storyboard or xib, which requires no code at all.  :)

Comment: @ABC Considering a scenario that I have only one last textField with text and I'm removing the whole text from it. At this case I will end up in your else condition and it says that I have to check all of my textFields. The point is that at this moment my instance variable will not be updated so I'm still having text on it. Else condition will work if I check all of my textFields except the current one. Did you get my point?

Comment: @vilelam, That is why I have added that you have to check with `[text length]` instead of `textField.text` in else part for current textField. Glad to see that my suggested approach of `if ([text length] > 0)` for enabling is implemented. That was one suggestion I had mainly with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

To @rmaddy answer. For every time `textField` editing, it will call that method and check the text length for that **SPECIFIC** `textField` and `enable or disable barButtonItem`. But the question is about enabling or disabling the UIBarButtonItem, **if any of the 6 textFields having text** then button should be enable. If none having text, then only it should be disable. So there is no option except iterating all `textFields` in your view. Instead of writing targets for each `textField` you can use `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`

just add that notification in `viewWillAppear`: method and remove it in `viewWillDisappear`: method

look at this code..

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(validateFields) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)validateFields {

    // I think you would have outlet for all textFields.So you can check the textfields having text or not ..
     if([textField1.text length] || [textField2.text length] || ....){
           [yourBarButton setEnabled:YES];
      }else{
           [yourBarButton setEnabled:NO];
      }
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

@rmaddy answer will work too. Don't forget to see the comments in else part of his answer.Now It's depend on the method which one user selects..

Answer (score 0):

View Controller M.

```
 if (text1.text.length > 0 || text2.text.length > 0 || text3.text.length > 0 || text4.text.length > 0 || text5.text.length > 0 || text6.text.length > 0)  {

    //btnBack is your UIBarButton   
    [btnBack setTitle:@""];
    [btnBack setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];
    [btnBack setEnabled:FALSE];
 } else {

     //btnBack is your UIBarButton     
     [btnBack setTitle:@"Done"];
     [btnBack setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];
     [btnBack setEnabled:TRUE];
 }
```

This code detects how long the textfield is and will enable or disable the UIBarButton!

Comment: You left out the hard part - when to set the button's property. :)

Comment: Slightly better. You are still missing all of the plumbing.